# Using a DLL function in C# that requires a pointer as argument, am I declaring this properly?

Tags: c#, pointers, memory, dll, external

I am developing an application with C# and have to call an external function from a DLL. This function requires a pointer to an integer array as an argument. The DLL documentation states that the integer array must have >= 4kb space allocation. I know C# steers away from pointers but I'm pretty sure I don't have a choice here, no? How do I allocate a pointer to an integer array and guarantee it is >= 4kb in size, in C#?

I have:

```
public readonly unsafe int*[] dataBuffer = new int*[1000];
```

But I am not sure if this is correct.

Method signature is

```
int DataRec(void* buf);
```

Comment: Please show the signature of the C method you want to call.

Comment: int DataRec(void* buf);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quite simple case, you just need a pointer to an array, not an array of pointers (as you have declared).

This should work:

```cs
byte[] buf = new byte[4096]; // allocate managed buffer
fixed (int* p = &buf[0]) // create a fixed pointer to the first element of the buffer (= to the buffer itself)
{ 
   int result = DataRec(p);
   // ...
   // use the data
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. So I've mostly made this work, but I have to declare p as a byte pointer instead of int pointer. If I wanted to keep it as an int pointer, I have to declare buf as such. Could I then do 'int[] buf = new int[1024]' and maintain my size requirement of 4kb? Sorry, I don't work at this level often.

Comment: If you need a byte pointer, just change it to that: `fixed (byte* p = &buf[0])`. If your function takes `void*`, it doesn't really matter what kind of pointer you pass, the value of the pointer is the same in all cases. `int[] buf = new int[1024]` gives a buffer of the same size, yes.